# Using parseJSON data within a for statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, var

I apologise in advanced for my lack of knowledge and most likely poor explanation of the problem i'm having with jQuery. I'm no wiz with jQuery but i would like to have multiple markers on my google map.

This is the code i'm using,

```
var locations_str = php_args.locations;
var locations = $.parseJSON(locations_str);

alert(locations_str);
```

And it alerts the following,

```
[{"title":"Rons Lounge","latitude":"53.372337","longitude":"0.011161"},{"title":"Early Keeps","latitude":"52.260010","longitude":"-1.172204"},{"title":"The Shed","latitude":"50.731153","longitude":"-1.854248"}
```

This is fine, but further on the script i need to make use of a 'for' statement so it outputs this from the parseJSON,

```
var markers = [
    ['Rons Lounge', 53.372337,0.011161],
    ['Early Keeps', 52.260010,1.172204],
    ['The Shed', 50.731153,-1.854248]
];
```

I'm almost there as i believe the 'for' statement is rather similiar to this,

```
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(locations[i].title));
}
```

Obviously without the alert, this was for testing and it alerts the titles of each one in the json.

Hope i made this clear enough and your help much appreciated.

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is something like

```
var markers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var location = locations[i];
    markers.push([location.title, location.latitude, location.longitude]);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thankyou for your response, ive replaced the code with yours and now it seems i'm getting an error. 'locations is not defined' my code, http://pastie.org/10274868

Comment: You still need to fetch your `json` and parse it into the `locations` variable like you were doing originally of course. This was just to replace your `for` loop.

Comment: Hmm, it seems when i move the var locations that fetches the json in the initialize() function the error appears...

Comment: Ah nevermind i used this instead var locations = jQuery.parseJSON(locations_str); Thankyou soo much :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var parsedObj = JSON.parse('[{"title":"Rons Lounge","latitude":"53.372337","longitude":"0.011161"},{"title":"Early Keeps","latitude":"52.260010","longitude":"-1.172204"},{"title":"The Shed","latitude":"50.731153","longitude":"-1.854248"}]');
var locationArr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < parsedObj.length; i++) {
  var temp = [];
  
  temp.push(parsedObj[i].title);
  temp.push(parsedObj[i].latitude);
  temp.push(parsedObj[i].longitude);
  
  locationArr.push(temp);
}

console.log(locationArr);
```